# add new extension disabled by sys admin

Tags: extension

wp 6.2 civi 5.6.2
i can't add an extension because "add new" is disabled.
Can i enable somewhere. I know how to install manually but would like this feature for other staff
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has probably been set in civicrm.settings.php as per https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/customize/extensions/#advanced-disable-automatic-installations-of-extension

`$civicrm_setting['Extension Preferences']['ext_repo_url'] = false;`

Either remove that or comment it out.